# Conditionally use computed column

Tags: sql-server, computed-column, default-value

IS it possible that a not nullable column can be setup to either
a) add value freely with INSERT/UPDATE query
b) if value not provided on insert, to avoid null entry added default the value to that of another column?

I know that with a computed column I can set the default to be another columns value, but I cannot then override this.

Comment: Does a [default constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-default-values-for-columns?view=sql-server-ver15) not work for you?

Comment: @Charlieface no, because a default doesn't allow you to default to another field's value, it is just a static value.

Answer (score 0):

An example:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (id INT,
>                    val INT);
> GO
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER tr
> ON test
> AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
> AS
> UPDATE test
> SET val = 123     -- custom value which must be set instead of NULL
>                   -- maybe any expression 
>                   -- and even an output of the subquery
> WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
>                FROM INSERTED
>                WHERE id = test.id
>                  AND val IS NULL );
> GO
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,1), (2,null), (3,3);
> SELECT * FROM test;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val
> -: | --:
>  1 |   1
>  2 | 123      -- NULL is replaced with custom value
>  3 |   3
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE test SET val = NULL where id = 1;
> SELECT * FROM test;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val
> -: | --:
>  1 | 123      -- NULL is replaced with custom value
>  2 | 123
>  3 |   3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3c460d8a240c5976a48e237a09d9e551)*

Answer (score 0):

While a **Trigger** would work probably just fine like in Akina's answer, I'm with Charlieface on using a [**Default Constraint**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-default-values-for-columns?view=sql-server-ver15) since this is exactly the kind of problem it was meant to solve, and is slightly *lighter* of a solution. It also lives as part of the table definition, instead of being a separate object on the server that needs to be maintained, so if you were to ever script your tables, the **Default Constraint** would automatically script with it, as opposed to a **Trigger**.

Example straight from Microsoft:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.doc_exz 
(
      column_a INT,
      column_b INT DEFAULT 50
);
```

The above will allow you to freely `INSERT` and `UPDATE` `column_b` but if you don't specify a value for `column_b` when you `INSERT` into the table, then it'll default to a value of `50`.

And here's the same example as above, but with specifying a name for the **Default Constraint**:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.doc_exz 
(
     column_a INT,
     column_b INT CONSTRAINT DF_Doc_Exz_Column_B DEFAULT 50
);
```